# Dojo javascript event and query selection issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

I have a menu item.

[image]

And I created event hanler to handle parent.

```
  on(query(".listMenu"), ".cBinfo:click", function (event) {
    if (event.type === 'click') {
        var toolTip = query(this).parent('li');
    }
  });
```

When I click this icon now, gives error.

**Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'parent'**

I write console console.log(query(this)) returns:

```
[span.cBinfo, _wrap: function, slice: function, splice: function, indexOf: function, lastIndexOf: function…]
```

But chrome watch expression resurns that breakpoint like this.

[image]

Comment: If you are using `dojo's functions` then you should remove `jquery` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the [`dojo/NodeList-traverse`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/NodeList-traverse.html) module loaded?